# Insert Values with foreign keys SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to insert data that has foreign keys. I am able to update the first two tables with the GUID but I am not able to do so in the last 3 tables I am trying to update

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier
    SET @myid = NEWID()

    INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Pod] (id)
    VALUES (@myid)

    INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[RackPattern] ([id])
    VALUES (@myid)

    INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[PhysicalServer] ([serialNumber], [rackPosition],[Rack_id], id)
    VALUES ('2327', '25', 'DBedc1001r01', @myid)

    INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Rack] ([Site_id], [Pod_id], [RackPattern_id], id)
    VALUES ('Datacenter','PostionID', 'RACK_PATTERN_ID_1', @myid)

    INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Site] (Pod_id, id)
    VALUES ('PostionID', @myid)

    COMMIT;
```

Results:

```
(1 row(s) affected)  

(1 row(s) affected)
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__PhysicalS__Rack___00DF2177". The conflict occurred in database "VCO01-A_PATTERN_DB", table "DB.Rack", column 'id'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 14
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Rack__Site_id__6BE40491". The conflict occurred in database "VCO01-A_PATTERN_DB", table "DB.Site", column 'id'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 17
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Site__Pod_id__4F47C5E3". The conflict occurred in database "VCO01-A_PATTERN_DB", table "DB.Pod", column 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you insert something into `PhysicalServer` in your third statement, which references `Rack` with a specific ID - but the insert into the `Rack` table only happens in the **fourth** statement - so that `Rack.Id` isn't going to be there (yet) when you run your third SQL statement! Same for the fifth statement - you insert a `Site` with an `id` - but you already reference that table in your fourth statement....

It's just a matter of **inserting in the RIGHT order** here - try this:

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

```
DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier
SET @myid = NEWID()

INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Pod] (id)
VALUES (@myid)

INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[RackPattern] ([id])
VALUES (@myid)

-- insert into SITE 
INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Site] (Pod_id, id)
VALUES ('PostionID', @myid)

-- insert into RACK, referencing the SITE
INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[Rack] ([Site_id], [Pod_id], [RackPattern_id], id)
VALUES ('Datacenter', 'PostionID', 'RACK_PATTERN_ID_1', @myid)

-- NOW you can insert into "PhysicalServer" which references the rack ...
INSERT INTO [SERVER].[DB].[PhysicalServer] ([serialNumber], [rackPosition],[Rack_id], id)
VALUES ('2327', '25', 'DBedc1001r01', @myid)

COMMIT;
```

But there's still something fishy.....

In the third statement you insert something into `Site` with an `id` that's this GUID you created. Yet in the fourth statement, you reference the `SiteId` as 'Datacenter' ...... something isn't right yet.....